# Updating artwork across multiple artboards simultaneously

Tags: adobe-illustrator, website-design, artboard, website-templates

If you have a navigation element like a header or footer that you are constantly changing and you want it to update simultaneously across multiple artboards is there a way to achieve this in Illustrator?

I thought an AI template would be the way to go but it just seems to place an object with a wireframe without rendering any artwork.

Pasting on all artboards comes pretty close, but requires you to manually run the feature every time and pastes a duplicate over the original.

Thanks in advance for any help on this.

Justin

Comment: It's so easy. After you finished designing the header convert it to a symbol. copy the generated symbol to all your artboards. Now when you want to modify your header just edit the symbol you just generate it.

Comment: Please leave that as an answer I feel like an idiot because I'm doing that everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

Converting your website header into a symbol to ensure having a single element that could be changed in any time reflecting into any place that symbol will be placed.

Here's my step by step solution

1. Open a new blacked document and set your document dimensions according to your website.

   2. Make a new dartboards

[image]

3. Draw you website header the way you like it.

[image]

4. Select all you artwork (Website header) and convert it into a Symbol by selecting it with the black arrow and drag and drop it into the `Symbols Panel`.

[image]

5. you will notice that the select artwork on your artboard converted into a symbol. Name it as you wish. I name it `Header`

[image]

6. Cut the new generated symbol <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> and past it into your all artboard all at once by going to `Edit > Past in All Artboards` or press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>

[image]

7. Now you will notice that you have an instance copy of your header distributed in all your artboards.

[image]

8. if you change the symbol you have just generate it will be reflected in your all Artboards instantly.
9. change the design of your website header by double click the `Header` symbol in the symbol panel or in your artboard .. you will edit your design in `Isolation Mode` where you can edit the `Header` symbol in separably.

[image]

10. You will notice that the changes will be reflected in the other Artboards instantly.

[image]

11. be ware that any changes in your old design will be permanently, so if you like to keep the old design make an instance of your old design and rename it into another name.

That's it.